# Hi all, Is there a query driven way to find out who created a particular table in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a specific schema in which i need to find who created certain tables. I already have table created date from dba_objects but i also need the username who created the table. Is there anyway to get this information through a query in oracle.

Comment: You can get the OWNER of a table but a user having `CREATE ANY TABLE` privilege can create a table owned by any user. Without an audit trail, you can't know for sure.

Comment: Of course, if anyone can log in as that owner and create a table, then you need a more comprehensive audit trail.

Comment: You have the "created date" in `dba_tables`? What Oracle version are you running? I am on Oracle 12.2.0.1 and I don't see "created date" in `dba_tables`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot identify the user who issued the create table statement retroactively unless you have previously enabled Unified Auditing and have the ORA_SECURECONFIG policy enabled:

```
select * from audit_unified_enabled_policies where policy_name = 'ORA_SECURECONFIG';
```

If it is enabled, simply look at unified_audit_trail, it should have the data you are looking for:

```
select dbusername 
from unified_audit_trail
where action_name = 'CREATE TABLE' 
and object_schema = '<target_schema>' 
and object_name = '<tablename>';
```

This policy I believe is not enabled by default but can easily be enabled for future needs:

```
audit policy ora_secureconfig;
```

Comment: I should clarify, this isn't the only policy that audits this activity; you or your team may have created / enabled any number of policies that would audit this action; ORA_SECURECONFIG is just the one that's built into a new DB.